Taylor Expansion of a vector-valued function with 2 vectors as input
Let a function $f(x,u): \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.
I wonder how to expand it around $(x_n, u_n)$.
For the time being, keeping it only up to the first order is enough
So I am looking for something:
$f(x_n + \Delta x ,u_n + \Delta u) = f(x_n) + \ ... $
But I am not quite sure how to approach this.
Thank you in advance for all the help!

It works just like a standard multivariate Taylor expansion.
$$
f(x_n+\Delta x_n,u_n+\Delta u_n) = f(x_n,u_n) + D_x(x_n,u_n)\Delta x_n + D_u(x_n,u_n)\Delta u_n + \mathcal{O}(\|\Delta x_n\|^2 + \|\Delta u_n\|^2),
$$
where $D_x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $D_u\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ are the Jacobian matrices obtained by differentiating $f$ with respect to $x$ and $u$, respectively. They can also be viewed as submatrices of a larger matrix $Df\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m+n}$ obtained by considering $f$ as a function from $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$ so that
$$
Df = \begin{bmatrix}D_x&|&D_u\end{bmatrix}.
$$

You need to replace the second $\Delta x_n$ by $\Delta u_n$. But we don't have the equality in the first centered formula.

Fixed the notation and added higher order terms

Great. --------
